# Integrating SonarQube (Swift) with Bamboo

Tags: sonarqube, bamboo, xcuitest

I tried SonarQube and sonar-scanner for my XCUItests locally on my machine using the docker image but now I want to integrate it with our CI (Bamboo), we already have our SonarQube server but I have no clue on next steps to integrate it to Bamboo.

I am using it for UI Tests in swift using XCUITest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Click add task and choose Sonar Scanner. Update the task with values, add if sub directory required, then additional param with -Dsonar.java.binaries=target/classes, update server value for your company, update project key as unique and save with other default values. It should work.

Comment: Thanks a lot. worked. the problem for me was that the CI agent was not configured correctly.

Comment: okay, Welcome. Usually the agent should get picked up based on operating system used. So if you use powershell or microsoft related tasks, then you can add OperatingSystems equals Windows. If curl script, you can use Linux. This setting can be done inside configure plan->stages and jobs-> requirements-> search for capability. If specific agent is configured to CI build, there is a possibility of agent unavailability issues.

Comment: Yes exactly this is what I discovered. So I put the correct capability and it worked just fine. I am using it for iOS projects.